# How to create a Javascript stubbed object during Rspec feature specs?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, modernizr

I have some current feature specs in rspec that currently test some javascript functionality. In those libraries, I am using Modernizr to detect primarily just `touchevents`. Since I am using Poltergeist and PhantomJS, `Modernizr.touchevents` always returns true even though I would prefer for it to return false to run other conditionals.

Is there a way to explicitly stub out `Modernizr.touchevents` or just Modernizr all together?

I have tried the following:

1. `Modernizr.touchevents = false`
2. `Modernizr.touchevents = {}`
3. `Modernizr = {}`
4. Do not include the modernizr library during tests, however my tests fail because I am expecting Modernizr to be there.

Even if its not Modernizr, how do you stub out javascript libraries especially if you don't care about its functionality at the moment of testing.

Thanks

Edit:

So far is it right just to perform, `Modernizr.touchevents = false;`? Will Modernizr reinitialize this if I set it? or is this permanent?

Edit 2:

Since I am using poltergeist and phantomjs, Modernizr believes that its a touch device. I want to be able to switch that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [rspec-rails docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/feature-specs/feature-spec):

> Feature specs are high-level tests meant to exercise slices of
>   functionality through an application. They should drive the
>   application only via its external interface, usually web pages.

Your feature specs should not do anything that a user cannot also do through the UI (eg: typing in a URL, clicking a link, etc.). Mocking/stubbing Javascript is not appropriate for this kind of test.

Comment: Since I am using poltergeist and phantomjs, Modernizr believes that its a touch device. I want to be able to switch that.

Comment: I'm not familiar with poltergeist, but it seems like you ought to be able to set the User-Agent to a value that will make it work as a non-touch device.